# How to alternately upcase/downcase a passed-in string by each characters index?

Tags: ruby, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

I ran across an odd thing working on a Codewars problem. Here are the instructions:

> Write a function toWeirdCase (weirdcase in Ruby) that accepts a string, and returns the same string with all even indexed characters in each word upper cased, and all odd indexed characters in each word lower cased. The indexing just explained is zero based, so the zero-ith index is even, therefore that character should be upper cased.
>
> The passed in string will only consist of alphabetical characters and spaces(' '). Spaces will only be present if there are multiple words. Words will be separated by a single space(' ').
>   Examples:

```
weirdcase( "String" )#=> returns "StRiNg"
weirdcase( "Weird string case" );#=> returns "WeIrD StRiNg CaSe"
```

Here's my code:

```
def weirdcase string

  @case = []

# Ternary:
  string.each_char { |c|
#    string.index(c).even? ? @case.push(c.upcase) : @case.push(c.downcase)
    c =~ /[[:alpha:]]/ ? (string.index(c).even? ? (@case.push(c.upcase)) : (@case.push(c.downcase))) : (string.index(c) + 1)
    }

# If/Then:
#  string.each_char { |c|
    #if string.index(c).even? && c != " " 
#    if c =~ /[[:alpha:]]/ && string.index(c).even?
#    then @case.push(c.upcase)
#    else @case.push(c.downcase)
#    end  }

  @case.join

end
p "TEST"
p weirdcase "this is a test"
p weirdcase "thisisatest"
p weirdcase " th is  is  a  t es t"
```

The results:

```
"TEST"
"ThIsIsATesT"
"ThIsIsATEsT"
"tHIsIsAtest"
weirdcase
should return the correct value for multiple words
Expected: "ThIs Is A TeSt", instead got: "ThIsIsATesT"
0 Passed
1 Failed
0 Errors

Process took 171ms to complete
```

And here are the tests:

```
describe 'weirdcase' do
  #it 'should return the correct value for a single word' do
   #  Test.assert_equals(weirdcase('This'), 'ThIs');
  #  Test.assert_equals(weirdcase('is'), 'Is');
  #end
  it 'should return the correct value for multiple words' do
    Test.assert_equals(weirdcase('This is a test'), 'ThIs Is A TeSt');
  end
end
```

I've tried writing this code a few different ways, and I keep getting the same result: instead of "ThIs Is A TeSt" for a result, I instead get "ThIsIsATesT" or some other variation where the alternating capitalization seems to fail once it reaches the word "test", which makes no sense to me - it seems to go against what the methods are supposed to do. I also tried it in irb, and saw the same result so I don't *think* its a Codewars bug.

I'm still relatively new at Ruby. Can anyone help me find the thing(s) I must be overlooking and/or explain how this code came to this result ?

### Update:

Everyone, thank you for your good advice. I updated the title to something more descriptive, and re-wrote this code from scratch to index-iterate over each word individually, instead of treating it like one long string. I'm still having some trouble with it though. Here's my new code:

```
def weirdcase string
  char = Array.new
  puts "string: #{string}"
  string.split(' ').each do |word|
    word.each_char.with_index do |c, index|
      if index.even?
        char.push(c.upcase)
      else
        char.push(c.downcase)
      end
    end
  end
  puts "char: #{char}"
  puts "char.join(''): #{char.join('')}"
  puts "char.join('space'): #{char.join(' ')}"

end
```

And here are the results:

```
weirdcase
should return the correct value for multiple words
string: This is a test
char: ["T", "h", "I", "s", "I", "s", "A", "T", "e", "S", "t"]
char.join(''): ThIsIsATeSt
char.join('space'): T h I s I s A T e S t
Expected: "ThIs Is A TeSt", instead got: nil
```

So the trouble I'm having now is how to properly concatenate the words with spaces in-between, instead of what you see above. I'm looking up ways to access the array entries properly after they are split initially. But of course I would welcome any more tips anyone might have :)

Comment: When your lines of code start to get so long like that, you should change the ternary operators into if/else statements.  Also, you should remove all the distracting comments from that code, and you should use a local variable (`case`) instead of an instance variable (`@case`).

Comment: Where did your spaces go? That might lead to the answer.

Comment: It looks like you are only pushing to your array if you determine you are dealing with a letter ([[:alpha:]]). You need to also push the spaces.

Comment: Oh, `case` is a reserved word, so you can't use `case` as a local variable name.  It was a bad name anyway; you should use something like `chars`, since it is an array of characters.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When creating a question, try to come up with a title that describes the actual problem you're trying to fix. "Another Codewars Oddity" doesn't tell anyone a thing about the question. That slows getting answers to your question and makes no sense to others searching for an answer to the same question.

Answer (score 2):

I think many of your problems are caused by this part of the code:

```
string.index(c).even?
```

Suppose `c` is equal to `'T'`.  Then `string.index(c)` will always return the index of the first letter T in your string, which is always zero, even if you are trying to process one of the T letters in the later part of your string.

To get the index of the chars as you are iterating over them, something like this should work:

```
string.each_char.with_index do |c, index|
  if index.even?
    #...
  else
    #...
  end
end
```

Comment: or `even = [true,false].cycle; string.each_char do |c|
  if even.next..else...end; end`.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in another answer, the `index(c)` call is the primary problem with your current code. It will return the first index in the string of a character matching the one requested (case-sensitive). Given your test string `"this is a test"`, since the first "t" has index 0 (even) ALL (lowercase) t's will be capitalized, and since the first "s" has index 3 (odd) ALL (lowercase) s's will be lowercased. That said, it looks like you might be slightly misreading part of the problem:

> all even indexed characters **in each word** upper cased, and all odd indexed characters **in each word** lower cased.

In their example, they give you this one

```
weirdcase( "Weird string case" );#=> returns "WeIrD StRiNg CaSe"
```

If you look closely, based on that example, with multi-word strings it's not based on the absolute index in the string, it's based on the index of each letter within each word. If it were the former, you see this conversion (e = even index, o = odd index)

```
 eoeoeoeoeoeoeoeoe
"Weird string case" # => WeIrD StRiNg cAsE
```

Because the "c" in case is an odd index, so it would lowercase. But from their example, it's uppercase - each word is treated as if the first letter in the word is index 0 for that word.

I would recommend a) writing a method to apply the weirdcase to each word in the string, b) splitting the string up into words and applying weirdcase to each individually using that method you just wrote, and the c) joining them back together (don't forget to specify the character to join them with, e.g. `join(' ')`.

Comment: thank you for the explanation. Looking at the problem this way, I'm not surprised it wouldn't work. I re-wrote the code and added it to this post, still having some trouble though...

Answer (score 1):

### A Working Solution:

After much trial and error, I managed to put something together that works:

```
def weirdcase string
  arr, char, result = [],[],[]
  arr = string.split(' ').each_slice(string.split(' ').count).to_a.transpose
  arr.each_with_index do |arr_word, index|   
    arr_word.each_with_index do |word, sub_index| 
      word.each_char.with_index do |letter, letter_index| 
        letter_index.even? ? char.push(letter.upcase) : char.push(letter.downcase)
      end
    end
    result.push(char.join(''))
    char.clear
  end
  result.join(' ')
end
```

Its clunky and probably not very efficient, but it works. I had to:

1. split the string into the "arr" array in a manner that would create a sub-array for each word,
2. iterate over "arr" to access the words,
3. sub-iterate over each word to get access the letters in its sub-array,
4. sub-sub-iterate over the letters and upcase/downcase appropriately,
5. pass the modified letters one-at-a-time into the "char" array, where they were joined into a word again,
6. pass the word into the "result" array,
7. and then clear out the "char" array so it wouldn't concatenate the words together iteratively, like this:

   ["ThIs","ThIsIs","ThIsIsA","ThIsIsATeSt"]

It was starting from the very beginning on each iteration, and sticking all the words together as it went. This was the hardest part to figure out. I used a lot of put statements for error-checking and had to do a lot of trial-and-error before I figured it out. I imagine there's a way to make it move from one array element to the next instead of starting at the beginning every time, but out of frustration I used the 'char.clear' as a workaround. Like I said, its clunky. It also doesn't seem very efficient to have 3 nested 'do' statements, or 3 separate arrays either. Can anyone make any suggestions for making the code more efficient and/or more Ruby-ish?

If I can come up with an improved version, I'll add it here. And in case you're curious, here are the Codewars-Submit-Test results:

```
weirdcase
should return the correct value for a single word
Test Passed: Value == "ThIs"
Test Passed: Value == "Is"
Test Passed: Value == "A"
Test Passed: Value == "TeSt"
Test Passed: Value == "LoOkS"
Test Passed: Value == "LiKe"
Test Passed: Value == "YoU"
Test Passed: Value == "PaSsEd"
should return the correct value for multiple words
Test Passed: Value == "ThIs Is A TeSt"
Test Passed: Value == "LoOkS LiKe YoU PaSsEd"
Test Passed: Value == "ThIs Is ThE FiNaL TeSt CaSe"
Test Passed: Value == "JuSt KiDdInG"
Test Passed: Value == "Ok FiNe YoU ArE DoNe NoW"
```

Comment: Nice solution. The `each_char.with_index` combination is pretty clever. You definitely don't need so many levels of iteration, or that very complex string split into array of arrays of single words. Here's another version that might be slightly more Ruby-ish: http://repl.it/cZs/1